# Converting time.struct_time to list

Tags: python

In Python, how do I convert a `time.struct_time` such as

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=275, tm_isdst=-1)
```

to a list such as

```
[2012, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 275, -1]
```

My motivation: I'm storing `time.struct_time` objects like the former in a json file and, when I retrieve them, they are lists like the latter. I need to compare one such list with a `time.struct_time`; hence my question.

Comment: [example](http://ideone.com/HFH70T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it with `list(obj)`, ex:

> `>>>` a = time.gmtime()
>   `>>>` a
>   time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=2, tm_min=53, tm_sec=4, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=305, tm_isdst=0)
>   `>>>` list(a)
>   [2012, 10, 31, 2, 53, 4, 2, 305, 0]

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `list()` constructor will do what you need:

```
>>> t = time.localtime()
>>> list(t)
[2012, 10, 30, 22, 54, 25, 1, 304, 1]
```