# Converting list to time.struct_time

Tags: python

I came across this question: [Converting time.struct_time to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150580/converting-time-struct-time-to-list) and am wondering is there a way to go backwards, convert a list to time.struct_time.

```
[2012, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 275, -1]
```

to this

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=275, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: That is trivial. What seems to be the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: What may be trivial to you is not trivial to me. I've tried googling any built in functions that may be able to do the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just convert it like below

```py
l= [2012, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 275, -1]
import time
s = time.struct_time(l)
```

> Init signature: time.struct_time(iterable=(), /)
>   Docstring:
>
> The time value as returned by gmtime(), localtime(), and strptime(), and
>   accepted by asctime(), mktime() and strftime().  May be considered as a
>   sequence of 9 integers.
>
> Note that several fields' values are not the same as those defined by
>   the C language standard for struct tm.  For example, the value of the
>   field tm_year is the actual year, not year - 1900.  See individual
>   fields' descriptions for details.
>
> Type:           type
>
> Subclasses: